# Cleaner Way to Take Items from One List to Another

Tags: python, list, indexing

I've been writing a text adventure game, and at one point I need to take an item, which is given by user input, from one list and move it to another list. Specifically, is there any way to get the index of an item when you know the item name besides something like:

```
list_one = ["item one", "item two"]
index_one = list_one.index("item one")
```

The code I'm using in my script is:

```
player.items.append(start_room.items.pop(start_room.items.index(next)))
```

Where next is the input, and this seems very messy. If there's an easier way to go about this, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Is the ordering of items in the lists important? Can the lists contain duplicates? If the answer is "no" to both, you should be using sets instead of lists.

Comment: you can make a try here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python ;)

Comment: btw, don't name your variable `next`, it shadows the built-in function `next()`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you already know the item, there is no need to call `index` or `pop` or whatever:

```
list_one.remove (item)
list_two.append (item)
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use return of `pop()` method :

```
list_two.append( list_one.pop( list_one.index( item ) ) )
```

And if suddenly you decide to need index, you don't need to change much :

```
i = list_one.index( item )
list_two.append( list_one.pop( i ) )
```