# How can two items be randomly selected and moved from one list to another list?

Tags: python, random, sublist

I want a method to select two elements (as sub-lists) from one list and then move them to another list, while removing them from the first list.

My code:

```
A=[[17, 4, 10, 18, 11], [23, 16, 24, 29, 19, 12, 22], [15, 2, 32, 30, 20, 7, 25], [33, 21, 5, 13, 6, 28, 26, 31], [27, 8, 9, 14, 3]]
B = random.sample(A, 2)
      print("B",B)
```

My results:

```
B [[27, 8, 9, 14, 3], [33, 21, 5, 13, 6, 28, 26, 31]]
```

Expected results:

```
A [[17, 4, 10, 18, 11], [23, 16, 24, 29, 19, 12, 22], [15, 2, 32, 30, 20, 7, 25]]
B [[27, 8, 9, 14, 3], [33, 21, 5, 13, 6, 28, 26, 31]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cleaner Way to Take Items from One List to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440231/cleaner-way-to-take-items-from-one-list-to-another)

Comment: I checked the link, the programmer didn't consider random selection and down answer perfect, really thank you so much for your time.

Comment: You already knew how to do random selection, so what was missing is how to move items from one list to another.

Answer (score 4):

You could randomly select an index from `A` and `pop`/`append` from one list to the other

```
import random

A = [[17, 4, 10, 18, 11], [23, 16, 24, 29, 19, 12, 22], [15, 2, 32, 30, 20, 7, 25], [33, 21, 5, 13, 6, 28, 26, 31], [27, 8, 9, 14, 3]]
B = []

for _ in range(2):
    B.append(A.pop(random.randrange(0, len(A))))
```

Result

```
>>> A
[[15, 2, 32, 30, 20, 7, 25], [33, 21, 5, 13, 6, 28, 26, 31], [27, 8, 9, 14, 3]]
>>> B
[[23, 16, 24, 29, 19, 12, 22], [17, 4, 10, 18, 11]]
```

Note that you need to re-evaluate `len(A)` within your loop when you call `randrange` since the size is decreasing as you `pop` elements.

Comment: (there is also "randrange" almost the same as randint, but excluding the rightmost limiting value: with it that pesky "-1" is not needed.

Comment: @jsbueno Good call, edited my answer to include that, thanks

Comment: I will see randrange function, Thanks Sir for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

A not too performant solution:

```py
import random

A = [
    [17, 4, 10, 18, 11],
    [23, 16, 24, 29, 19, 12, 22],
    [15, 2, 32, 30, 20, 7, 25],
    [33, 21, 5, 13, 6, 28, 26, 31],
    [27, 8, 9, 14, 3],
]

B = []
for i in random.sample(range(len(A)), 2):
    B.append(A[i])
    A.remove(A[i])

A, B
>>>
([[17, 4, 10, 18, 11],
  [23, 16, 24, 29, 19, 12, 22],
  [33, 21, 5, 13, 6, 28, 26, 31]],
 [[15, 2, 32, 30, 20, 7, 25], [27, 8, 9, 14, 3]])
```

A more effective one:

```py
idx = sorted(random.sample(range(len(A)), 2))
A_new = []
B = []
for i, a in enumerate(A):
    if i in idx:
        B.append(a)
        idx = idx[1:]
    else:
        A.append(a)

A = A_new
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way would be to just iterate over the elements you have in B and removing them from A after the sampling.

```
for el in B:
    A.remove(el)
```

```
>>> A
[[15, 2, 32, 30, 20, 7, 25], [33, 21, 5, 13, 6, 28, 26, 31], [27, 8, 9, 14, 3]]
>>> B
[[23, 16, 24, 29, 19, 12, 22], [17, 4, 10, 18, 11]]
```

Comment: But this does not do it randomly

Comment: @PCM It assumes that `B` already contains the randomly selected items as shown in the question.

Comment: Yes exactly. The sampling of B has already been done.

Answer (score 1):

one possible solution

```
import random 
A=[[17, 4, 10, 18, 11], [23, 16, 24, 29, 19, 12, 22], [15, 2, 32, 30, 20, 7, 25], [33, 21, 5, 13, 6, 28, 26, 31], [27, 8, 9, 14, 3]]
B_with_index = random.sample((list(enumerate(A))), 2)

B = []
for element in B_with_index:
    
    B.append(element[1])
    A.pop(element[0])
```